# Accepting an array with n elements in a function - Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, parameters

Is there a way in which I can set a function to accept an array with a certain number of elements as a parameter?

I am wondering whether this is possible in the parameter section itself and not through some sort of validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this would be possible in Python to my knowledge,
this may not be what you want but this might work:

```
def foo(array, array_length):
  if array_length != len(array):
    return

  # function code
```

Comment: That does work yes, but I was wondering whether it was possible in the parameter area itself. It apparently is not however, thanks.